# I am having trouble copying directories

Tags: python

I am trying to copy my Automater workflows, I have listed them in a config file, and I would like to loop through the config file and copy the directories.  They have spaces in the names and I am having trouble.

It prints the filename correctly etc but the copy fails as there seems to be extra " " around the name with the copy

```
import os
import shutil

confdir=os.getenv("my_config")
dropbox=os.getenv("dropbox")
conffile = ('services.conf')
conffilename=os.path.join(confdir, conffile)    
sourcedir= (r'~/Library/Services/')
destdir=os.path.join(dropbox, "My_backups")

for file_name in open(conffilename):
    sourcefile=os.path.join(sourcedir, repr(file_name.strip()))
    print sourcefile
    destfile=os.path.join(destdir, file_name.strip())
    shutil.copytree(sourcefile, destfile)
```

And the error is

```
~/Library/Services/'Add PDF Metadata.workflow'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(sourcefile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",     line 168, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "~/Library/Services/'Add PDF Metadata.workflow'"
```

Thanks in advance

I have tried the suggestions below but it still is not working

Comment: I managed to resolve it all here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052341/i-seem-to-get-an-error-although-the-script-runs-i-cant-see-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't like the ~ I put the full path in.  I have also just edited one more bit and used sourcedir=os.path.expanduser('~/Library/Services/') to expand the home directory

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `repr()` on `file_name.strip()`? That will surround your filename with single quotes - and those aren't present in the file path. Remove the `repr()`, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I was using the repr() on the file name as there are spaces in the name.  I have tried without the repr() and I still get the same error

Comment: And you are sure that the file in that error message exists in the source directory?

Comment: Yes Macintosh-3:Config craigdba$ ls -l ~/Library/Services/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 craigdba  craigdba  102  1 Oct 17:25 Add PDF Metadata.workflow
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 craigdba  craigdba  102  1 Oct 17:17 Add Spotlight Comments.workflow
drwxr-xr-x  3 craigdba  admin     102 20 Nov  2007 NoteBookHelper.service

Answer (score 0):

[`shutil.copytree(src, dst)`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) will recursively copy a directory tree (and all the files in it) located at `src` to  a new directory tree at `dst`. It is not meant to be used with files.

Here, you want to copy single files around, not a complete directory tree, you should just use [`shutil.copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) or `shutil.copy2`.

If the files may be located in a directory tree that you want to reproduce, then you could use  [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) for the path returned by [`os.path.dirname(destfile)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) before calling `shutil.copy(sourcefile)` to actually copy the file to `destfile`.

However, be aware that calling  `os.makedirs` with a destination that already exists will raise an error so you probably want to `try / except`.

Comment: It is a directory I want to copy

Comment: @geekcomputers Oh, you're right, the `"~/Library/Services/'Add PDF Metadata.workflow'"` got me confused. Could you post the new error message now that you removed the `repr()` call?

Comment: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Library/Services/Add PDF Metadata.workflow'