# I seem to get an error although the script runs, I can't see why

Tags: python

I have a piece of code here that copies a list of directories etc from a config file.  It runs and copies the directories etc but it still errors each time it runs, can anyone help me to understand why the error pops up or is there a way I can surpress it

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "copydir.py", line 22, in <module>
        shutil.copytree(sourcefile, destfile)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 174, in copytree
        os.makedirs(dst)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/export/home/craigdba/My_backups/2012-10-24/'
```

The Code is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import shutil
import datetime
import os

today=datetime.date.today()
todaystr=today.isoformat()

confdir=os.getenv("my_config")
dropbox=os.getenv("dropbox")
conffile = ('services.conf')
conffilename=os.path.join(confdir, conffile)
sourcedir=(r'/export/home/craigdba/')
destdir=os.path.join(dropbox, "My_backups"+"/"+todaystr+"/")
#os.makedirs(destdir)

for file_name in open(conffilename):
  sourcefile=os.path.join(sourcedir, file_name.strip())
  destfile=os.path.join(destdir, file_name.strip())
  shutil.copytree(sourcefile, destfile)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That error simply means you attempted to create a directory that already exists.

Comment: I understand that, if occurs even if I delete the directories before I run the script.  Do you know of a way I could suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have an empty line in your `servicers.conf`, may be at the end of file?

You can filter those in your code by checking:

```
fname = file_name.strip()
if fname:
    sourcefile = os.path.join(...)
    ...
```

Comment: Yes that was the case.  This has solved my issue.  Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking to see if your destination directory exists before attempting to create it:

```
if not os.path.exists(destdir):
    os.makedirs(destdir)
```

Comment: That won't necessarily work because the juice behind os.makedirs() is that it'll create any intermediate directories in the path that don't yet exist.

Comment: I just double checked and os.makedirs only errors out if the final element of the path already exists.  If it didn't behave this way, it would always error out, because the root of a path always already exists.

Comment: I stand corrected - good point. If any intermediate doesn't exist, and the final directory doesn't exist - your solution is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix this would be to delete the destination directory and then you are replacing it with the new directory anyway.

First check if the directory exists, if it does not make one.